# About LQR control for scalar discrete-time control system

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

It's an [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216865/lqr-control-for-scalar-discrete-time-control-system)

> Consider the following scalar discrete-time control system
> $$x(k + 1) = 2x(k) + u(k)$$ where $x \in \mathbb R$, $u \in \mathbb R$ and $x(0) = −2$. Let $N > 1$ be some integer.

> 1. Consider the following cost function $$J = \sum_{k=0}^{N} u(k)^2$$ Find the optimal control law and the minimal cost.

> 2. Consider the following cost function $$J = \sum_{k=0}^{N} x(k)^2$$ Find the optimal control law and the minimal cost.

> 3. Consider the optimal control problem of $2.$ with the constraint $|u(k)| \leq 0.5$. Find the optimal control law.

I'm new to optimal control theory and confused now by the first hint given in the first answer to the original post.

"Do you see how the cost can be minimized if we do not care about the state x?", does this means that a zero $u(t)$ will minimize the cost? If so, what if $J=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}||u(t)||^2$, zero again?

Comment: Yes, a zero input will minimize the cost. Same thing for an infinite horizon.

Comment: @KBS Thank you, it's a problem from my assignment with 18 marks, I cannot even believe that such a trivial solution would be correct in the assignment. As you have confirm this, I'm relaxed now.

Comment: @KBS I think this is not correct at least for the infinite horizon because LQR theory requires minimization of $J$ over *stabilizing* $u$ and since $u\equiv 0$ does not stabilize the system it violates the stability constraint (since the uncontrolled system is unstable). I am not 100% sure how the LQR optimization problem is precisely defined for a finite horizon (can't remember right now) but I would expect that LQR with finite horizon still requires that $u$ is stabilizing.

Comment: For the infinite horizon this can be confirmed with Matlab: `K=dlqr(2,1,0,1)` gives `K=1.5` so $u(k)=-1.5x(k)$ is optimal for $J=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}||u(k)||^2$, given that $x(k+1)=2x(k) + u(k)$.

Comment: For finite-horizon, stability is not an issue and is not considered. However, optimal control over an infinite-horizon is not necessarily for stabilizing $u$. It is, for instance, implicitly the case whenever the pair $(A,C)$ is observable with $Q=C^TC$. This is why this condition is sometimes required but $u$ is not sought to be stabilizing per say.

Comment: The reason why Matlab looks for a stabilizing control is that it assumes a controller of the form $u=Kx$, and therefore the closed-loop system must be stable for the cost, which now depends on the state, to be finite. However, this is not the optimal solution of the optimization problem, per say, which is $u\equiv0$ in both cases. Without context, it is difficult to decide which answer will be correct. On one hand, you need to solve the Riccati equation for $Q=0$ and get the controller you mention while on the other hand you can solve the problem directly and get $u\equiv0$.

Comment: @KBS For general optimal control that is true but since the question is explicitly about LQR the constraint that $u$ must be stabilizing (for the infinite horizon) cannot be ignored since this is a requirement in LQR theory.

Comment: @KBS Regarding the comment about Matlab, this is not correct because I passed $Q=0$ to the cost function (remember that $Q$ is only required to be negative semi-definite), so the cost does in fact not depend on the state. However, a non-zero $u$ is required exactly to satisfy the stability constraint. You can check this if you pass an $A$ matrix to the `dlqr` function which is stable without control, eg `K=dlqr(0.5,1,0,1)`, this will yield `K=0` as expected. The specific form $u=-Kx$ is not assumed a priori but it is a result of LQR theory that the optimal, stabilizing $u$ has that form.

Comment: Then, it seems that the set of admissible control inputs is that of stabilizing ones, as you said.